# Is using HashMap to count map by iteratively updating the values a good practice?

Tags: java, hashmap, collision

I've frequently used a hashmap to count values such as:

```
  HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  for(String word : wordList) {
       if(map.contains(word)) 
           map.put(word, map.get(word)+1)); 
       else 
           map.put(word, 1);
  }
```

Is this an acceptable practice? Since put/get operation usually takes O(1) unless there is a collision, which would require O(n) when that happens.

Another way I can think of would be using a hashmap that contains an index of the word, and use an array, which would require one iteration of the list, but given that it might happen anyway due to the collision in the first way, maybe it's better. This way, you would take up more memory to save another index hashmap.

What do you guys usually do/recommend when you have to do the counting of the words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most cases `HashMap` is adequate. But Guava's [`Multiset`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) is a lot more comfortable to use as it takes care of the boilerplate code.

For really large sets of words though you might want to use an optimised hash function because [the one built into `String` is known to produce quite a lot of collisions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145633/13625).

If your strings aren't very long but you have lots of it, a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) may have a better worst case performance.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Guava [Multiset](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).  This is exactly what it's designed for.